# Read SXA Search Scope in Code

Tags: sxa, content-search, sxa-search

everyone ,

I've to read the SXA search scope in my code. I am using the search result component on my page and added some custom filters in the search scope. So I need the applied search filter on my page for further logic. how should I read the filter?

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/use-the-sxa-search-components.html see search box scope

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean with "I need the search filter on my page"?